# Scroll Magic JS Margin Issue

Tags: scrollmagic

It throw this below error

**ScrollMagic.min.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: margins is not defined**

Scroll not work. If I reduce height it works some time

Answer (score 0):

I edited the Scrollmagic.js file and changed line 677 to 680 to this:

```
var margins = {};
i.forEach(function(e) {
margins[e] = n[e] || ""
});
r.css(t, margins);
```

That resolves the variable not existing error. Not too sure about knock on though.